# Why are these values of this dot product expression not equal?

Tags: vectors

This is a worked example of dot products from [Maths Is Fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html):

[image]

Why are the answers only the same when rounded if the formulas are mathematically equal?

Comment: Inaccuracies with the use of $\cos(59.5^\circ)$'s approximation as opposed to the exact value of $\cos(59.5^\circ)$, or also possible is that the value of $59.5^\circ$ was an approximation itself to begin with.

Comment: Rearranging, $\cos(\theta)=\frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|\cdot \|b\|}=\frac{66}{130}$ we get that in fact $\theta = \arccos(\frac{66}{130})$ is closer to  $=59.49^\circ$ not $59.5^\circ$ as pictured:  calculations: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos(66%2F130)+in+degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle that they put into $\cos(\theta)$ was an approximation itself.

If the exact angles were used, identical answers would be yielded.